# What is "Residency (Tuition) Claim" in the US universities?

Tags: phd, united-states, university

I am an international student and applying for Ph.D. in a university in the US. The application portal is prompting me to select (Yes/No) the "**Residency (Tuition) Claim**" of that state. It is saying in-state and out-of-state and something like that. I cannot understand what this is.

I am going to do the Ph.D. and it will probably take 5-6 years to complete it. So, what should I do?

Requesting suggestions. Thanks...

Comment: US universities often have different tuition fees for in state and out of state students. So it is probably asking if you are a resident of the state the university is in for tuition purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For state sponsored universities, such as the University of Wisconsin, if a person has established "residency" in that state prior to enrollment, they get a lower tuition rate since the state itself sponsors them to a degree.

The rules for establishing residency vary by state, but it means more than just living there at the moment. It usually involves some period of time with a residence in the state, and therefore paying property taxes there.

Out of state students, including international students, don't have residency and haven't paid taxes there, so are charged a tuition that is closer to the actual cost of providing the education - though usually still less, since the state still subsidizes things to some extent.

In the past, in-state tuition was very low, but that is changing as the willingness of legislators to actually fund education adequately has declined in recent years.

Each state will have its own rules about this. There is no national higher education system in the US. In some cases it might be possible for a student to start out as an out of state student and, along the way, establish residency, and then pay in-state tuition.

But note that most PhD students in the US serve as TAs (or RAs) and those jobs almost always come with tuition forgiveness. So, if you have a TA, the difference is probably moot.

Comment: Thanks, sir... I will get a RA with fully funded stipends. Should I select "No, I do not claim the residency", then ?? And Yes, I am applying to the University of Wisconsin-Madison..

Comment: Excellent. Yes, select non residency. UW was just a guess. Great school though. But, sadly, a football rival of the place I went. And you may get to meet Bryan Krause.

Comment: @Buffy Alas, that final perk hasn't yet made it to the university's recruiting materials...

Comment: Actually, @BryanKrause, UW wasn't even a guess, just an example. I was thinking of schools that are great in math, specifically, not unlike my own (doctoral) alma-mater. But the "perk' will appear in a recruiting doc - soonish. Right after you win the Nobel for conquering COVID, cancer, and teenage zits.

Answer (score 0):

Choose "out of state" unless you are a resident of that US state for tuition purposes, or perhaps a resident of another US state with a reciprocity agreement. Living there while a student doesn't count as residency for tuition purposes (there may be special exceptions to this, and if you were a domestic student it would definitely be worth studying more how your specific state or university defines things). As an international student you are not a resident of any US state for tuition purposes.

If your PhD is funded in some way that includes tuition remission (typical of US PhDs), it won't really matter for you whether your tuition is at the "resident" or "non-resident rate": you won't pay any tuition so the number doesn't matter (except perhaps for internal accounting, which isn't really your business). If your PhD is not funded, it's going to be extremely expensive for you and unless you or your family is wealthy enough to not care about such things you should not attend such a program.

Comment: No, My Ph.D. is fully funded covering tuition and living expenses and everything else. I will get a Research Assistantship. So, should I select, "No, I do not claim the residency"?

Comment: @DonaldAlvarez Yes, correct.